# Google Sheets: How to set conditional formatting based on checkboxes with Scripts for over a 100 lines

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to be able to change the background color, font color, and strikethrough of column A, B, & C based on the checkbox of column D. EX: If in row 2 column D is checked, then A, B, C of row 2 ONLY will change colors and strikethrough. I need this to continue for hundreds of lines. This formatting will only apply to "sheet3" and ignoring row 1. The colors that I need are listed below:

```
.setBackground("#EFEFEF")
.setFontColor("#CCCCCC")
.setStrikethrough(true)
```

Below is the current script I already have for sorting if any of this is helpful.

```
function SortData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var myRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow-1,4)

  myRange.sort([{column:4,ascending:true}, {column:3,ascending:true}])

}

function onEdit(e){

  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var curSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  var value = e.range.getValue();

  if(row != 1 && curSheet == "Sheet3" ){
SortData();

  }}
```

Thank you SO much for your help!

```
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('A:C')])
  .whenFormulaSatisfied('=$D=TRUE')
  .setBackground('#EFEFEF')
  .setStrikethrough(true)
  .setFontColor('#CCCCCC')
  .build());
```

I've tried this, I'm very new to this, so everything on this tried part could be completely wrong. It's fine if it is. I just want it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  e.source.toast("Gate1");
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet3" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 3).setBackground("#EFEFEF").setFontColor("#CCCCCC").setFontLine("line-through");
    SortData();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, thank you so much! It works, but my sorting from my previous stuff is not working anymore. Any idea why or how to fix it?